# Realizing on-side connection

Tags: django, django-models

How to realize on-side connection in Django models?
Say, I want to realize "friendship" mechanism, i.e., if you add me to your friends list it doesn't mean that you are in my friends list.
I tried to use

```
models.ManyToManyField("self")
```

But in this case both-side friendship is realized.

Answer (score 1):

Make another model:

```
class Friendship(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="friends")
    friend = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="opposite_friends")
```

Now you can query like this:

```
someuser.friends.all() # all your friends
someuser.opposite_friends.all() # users that have you as a friend
```